# Srvnet service is not starting in windows container

Tags: docker, smb, windows-container, windows-server-container

I need to start file sharing service on windows container
One of my application wants to access folder inside the container through //hostname or ip address/C$/C/windows like this

How can I make it running

ON checking why this is not running found that it is dependent on lanmanserver service and that is dependent on Samss and Srvv2 driver that is also dependent on srvnet actually srvnet is the base dependency . srvnet is dependent on msquisc kernal driver and that is perfectly running but from srvnet it is not running, why ? please help me on this .

Comment: IS this running in a dev environment? You could use SMB Mounts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/persistent-storage#smb-mounts